# What are "asses' ears" in this sentence from Moby Dick?

Tags: meaning

I was reading through *Moby Dick* and found this sentence:

> Two enormous wooden pots painted black, and suspended by asses’ ears, swung from the cross-trees of an old top-mast, planted in front of an old doorway.

What does "asses' ears" mean in this context?

Comment: I would guess that this is talking about "ears" projecting upward on either side of the pots, to facilitate hanging them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My annotated edition of *Moby-Dick, or, The Whale* (Bobbs-Merrill, 1964), edited by Charles Feidelson, Jr., contains this very brief explanatory note about "asses' ears":

> Ear-shaped handles.

Likewise, Kathleen Kier, [*A Melville Encyclopedia: A–Loom*](https://books.google.com/books?id=iwdbAAAAMAAJ&q=%22asses+ears%22+handles&dq=%22asses+ears%22+handles&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj76e_n6_3WAhVCllQKHaxnAqoQ6AEIPjAE) (1990) has this:

> **ASSES' EARS** Handles so shaped. M[oby] D[ick, chapter] 15

And Clarence Babcock & David Maurer, [*Some Expressions from Herman Melville*](https://books.google.com/books?id=f5sOAQAAIAAJ&q=%22asses+ears%22+handles&dq=%22asses+ears%22+handles&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj76e_n6_3WAhVCllQKHaxnAqoQ6AEIVjAI) (1959) has this:

> **asses' ears:** *n.* Ear-shaped lugs or handles (as explained by Willard Thorp in his annotated ed. of *Moby-Dick*). — 1851 *Moby-Dick* I, 80

Thorp's edition of *Moby-Dick* was published by Oxford University Press in 1947. Unfortunately, I haven't been able to find a searchable copy of it online, so I can't reproduce his explanation here.

Mary Reichardt's edition of [Moby-Dick](https://books.google.com/books?id=o9y2fZlFRpUC&pg=PA100&dq=%22suspended+by+asses+ears%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi0h6j_8f3WAhUoxFQKHTgKBzgQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=%22suspended%20by%20asses%20ears%22&f=false) (Ignatius Press, 2011) goes into somewhat greater detail than the other sources cited here:

> *asses' ears*: iron supports that look like the ears of donkeys.

Interestingly, a certain Greek bottle is described in W. Harris, [*Homiletical Commentary on the Books of Samuel*](https://books.google.com/books?id=ELACAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA169&dq=%22asses+ears%22+handles&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj76e_n6_3WAhVCllQKHaxnAqoQ6AEIODAD#v=onepage&q=%22asses%20ears%22%20handles&f=false) (1884) as having similarly shaped handles:

> *Reland* adduces a great number of quotations from Greek writers, showing that the ancients used a bottle with two long handles, which, from their resemblance to asses' ears, were called (ονοι) asses ; and the Greek poet *Sosibus* says of one of his heroes, "He ate three times in the space of a single day three great asses of bread, which *Casaubon* understood to signify the *lading of three asses*, whereas the true meaning is the contents of three vases or jars called asses." (*Jamieson*).

Comment: Yeah, I spent maybe 20 minutes searching through Ngram hits, and, aside from references to Midas and some other mythical folks, the term seemed to be often used to describe a shape, similar to the ears of an ass (donkey). https://metrouk2.files.wordpress.com/2013/05/donkey.jpg?quality=80&strip=all&strip=all